# Rails: Ransack Gem using dropdown - "undefined method name" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I am using the Ransack gem to create a filter form for my table.

In my controller (I am taking the filter options from another table):
homeworks_controller:

```
...     @q = Homework.search(params[:q])
        @sub = Homework.find_by_sql("SELECT subject FROM classmodules GROUP BY subject").map &:subject
        @q.build_condition if @q.conditions.empty?
        @q.build_sort if @q.sorts.empty?
...
```

In my view

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
     <%= f.select :subject_eq, @sub %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

Models

```
        classmodule.rb
        has_many :homeworks, :class_name => 'Homework'

        homework.rb
        belongs_to :classmodule, :class_name => 'Classmodule', :foreign_key => :subject
```

I get "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" as an error.

I searched for an answer but nothing solid for this and tried some suggested solutions. I'm stuck, any ideas? Thanks